# Why my UItableView doesn't scroll horizontally whereas I did set ContentSize larger?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

I have put some fields + an UITableVIew (named myTableView) within a scrollview (named parentScrollView). Now My TableView contains multiple columns so since it's a scrollview inside a scrollview I tried this in ViewDidLoad:

```
[[self parentScrollView] setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
self.myTableView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(640,300);
```

Only parentScrollView scrolls vertically not myTableView horizontally, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to make a spreadsheet is to insert a horizontal tableview for each row in the main vertical tableview.

The idea to create a horizontal tableview is to make a normal vertical tableview and then do some graphics translation to rotate 90 degree, so that it can become horizontal. Similar to PULSE iphone application. (Do check that !!!)

If you want, i can provide some code, to do the same.

Update : link for tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1

Comment: Is it pulse phone app that measures heart beat ? And yes of course I will be very interested by some code thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

This is by design

> A table view in the UIKit framework is limited to a single column because it is designed for a device with a small screen. UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, which allows users to scroll through the table, although UITableView allows vertical scrolling only.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: So I'm stuck ? How do people does something like a spreadsheet then ? They do it from scratch ?

Comment: I think so. `UIScrollView` subclass will be a great starting point. To improve performance and reduce memory consumption some tricks like cells caching should be used, like `UITableView` do by reusing its cells.